# Trouble with downloading data from web site

Tags: c#, .net

Basically I have no experience with downloading a web page and I'm trying to get this page which has daily stock exchange prices with no luck. I'm not sure if it's me doing something wrong here or if the web server disallows this kind of requests. Site works with chrome or IE.

```
               using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
           {

               byte[] response = client.DownloadData("http://limun.hr/main.aspx?id=18");
               string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
           }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to include what is wrong. Returned string contains only one character - @.

Comment: Try being more precise. What precisely is not working for you. What do you get and what did you expect to get instead

Comment: Does that not work?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites look at the UserAgent string in HTTP headers to see if the caller is an actual web browser. If you use the [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class you have more control over the call and can spoof the UserAgent string to simulate a real web browser. Try something like the following to make it work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://limun.hr/main.aspx?id=18") as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla /5.0 (Compatible MSIE 9.0;Windows NT 6.1;WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(););
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Comment: Yep. You've nailed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed that the UserAgent string in the HTTP headers is wrong, but you can add that string in the headers using the `WebClient` class, and keep your code simpler:

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla /5.0 (Compatible MSIE 9.0;Windows NT 6.1;WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
            string res = client.DownloadString("http://limun.hr/main.aspx?id=18");
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
```

*Note*: `WebClient` also has a `DownloadStringTaskAsync` method, which you may find useful, depending on your needs.